# Are method level singleton instances Thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, singleton

Are the operations on obj below thread safe? I know that method level variables and instances go on each thread's stack - but im not sure what will happen when the local variable is a singleton. foo() is called in a webservice call. I'm curious whether this is thread-safe?

```
public void foo() {
    SomeObject obj = getSomeObject();  
    obj.doSomething();   // Would this be thread safe?
}

private SomeObject getSomeObject() {
    // returns singleton
    SpringContext.getBean("someObject");
}

class SomeObject {
    int x;
      ...

    // Not synchronized
    public void doSomething() {

    }
}
```

Comment: if its a singleton (that depands on how u defined it in spring) then no way this is thread safe. you can do a test and chk of course

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you mean by "thread-safe". If `SomeObject.doSomething()` mutates the instance in an unsafe way, then no, it's not safe. Two different threads could obtain references to the same object.

Basically, unless `SomeObject` is designed to be used from multiple threads concurrently, you shouldn't be making it a singleton.

Comment: Am curious - does this apply to singleton local variables alone? ie  - if SomeObject was NOT a singleton. Would this then be threadsafe?

Comment: I would say that `SomeObject` needs to be protected if it is used by multiple threads.  I wouldn't say that it should not be a singleton given that Spring by default generates singleton beans.

Comment: If `SomeObject` was created per-thread, like with a `ThreadLocal`, then you would be threadsafe @Preator.  It's about whether multiple threads use the same object.

Comment: @PreatorDarmatheon: It would entirely depend on how you were fetching it. Basically, if you've got multiple threads with unfettered access to an object, that object had better be thread-safe...

Comment: @Gray: What do you mean by "protected" in this context? If you mean it should be designed to be used from multiple threads concurrently, then you're not disagreeing with my answer.

Comment: I mean that you would need to lock around it's usage or write the class to make it thread safe @Jon.

Comment: @Gray: If a class isn't designed to be used from multiple threads, using it that way by locking *everywhere* is a really fragile approach, IMO. Far better to avoid exposing it in an unsafe way to start with - e.g. by creating a thread-safe wrapper if necessary.

Comment: I agree @Jon.  I was just pointing out that the OP is getting the object from Spring so making it not a singleton is not necessarily trivial.

Comment: @Gray- the second part was hypothetical - though my original scenario does a spring lookup - I could simply create an instance (not going to do it officially) - but the question was more for clearing cobwebs about singletons references within a method call.

Answer (score 4):

It is thread safe only if the `SomeObject` is itself thread-safe.  If, for example, you read and can change the value of `x` in the `doSomething()` call then it would not be thread safe unless it was appropriately locked.

Without knowing more about `SomeObject` it is impossible to tell exactly whether or not you would have a problem.

Comment: It doesn't have to be immutable - `doSomething` may not be a synchronized method, but it could still be synchronizing internally, or possibly it could mutate an `AtomicInteger` etc.

Comment: class SomeObject {
    // Not synchronized
    public void doSomething() {
       int x;
    }
}   So I'm guessing THIS would be thread safe? (no class level variables)

Comment: Again it depends on the rest of the code of `SomeObject` @Preator.  If all you were dealing with is local calculations on the stack, then yes, it would be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Method/Thread locality may be lost completely when you make any static reference. Since the reference is static the local field pointing to the static reference is not on the thread stack, it may in fact be referenced by other threads.

You have the same thread-safety effect if the Object was assigned globally instead of thread-local.

```
final SomeObject obj = getSomeObject();
public void foo() {
    obj.doSomething();  
}

private SomeObject getSomeObject() {
    // returns singleton
    SpringContext.getBean("someObject");
}
```